# Spring JPA Two Entities for same DB table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing Spring Boot Data JPA application and I have following situation:

I have 2 database queries fetching from same table but they are fetching different columns and data based on their `WHERE` clauses.  For example:

```
SELECT CAR_TYPE, CAR_MODEL, CAR_YEAR, ACCIDENT_YEAR, BUY_DAY FROM CAR WHERE ACCIDENT_YEAR IS NULL
```

, and

```
SELECT CAR_MODEL, CAR_YEAR FROM CAR WHERE CAR_YEAR >= CURRENT_YEAR
```

As you can see these 2 queries (**whose results will be exposed through 2 different API points**) reference the same table `CAR`, but return different fields and have different `WHERE` clauses.

I know in JPA, I have to create an entity `CarEntity` like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class CarEntity {
   // I can only have fields from one or the other query 
   // here, so I guess I have to have 2 of these
}
```

, but my problem is that this entity needs to apply for the 2 different queries (with different fields returned, different data, different `WHERE` clauses).

So, it looks like I have to have actually 2 `CarEntity` classes.  But, I am not sure how to make these 2 `CarEntities` so they both reference the same table `CAR`?

Comment: If you want to select only two columns, why not use a [Spring Data JPA projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)?

Comment: @ChinHuang. it looks like you are right, thank you.  At first I wasnt following what you mean.  I will take a look into projections, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by using projection that basically you define an interface with field methods which you want to get them. [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

```
@Entity
public class Car implement CarSummary { // if you want you can implement JIC
  
  private UUID id;
  private String carType;
  private String carModel;
  private LocalDateTime carYear;
  
  //getters and setters

}


public interface CarSummary {

  String getCardModel();
  String getCarYear();

}
```

Then on your query.

```
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, UUID> {
  Collection<CarSummary> findByCarYearGreaterThan(LocalDateTime now);
  Collection<Car> findByAccidentYearIsNull();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this is what I am asking but thank you.  I also dont understand anything about Projections so will have to read and check but it sounds to complex and I cannot wrap my head around that.  But from what I gather, it does not seem to be what I ask for.  What I have problem with is that I seem to need to have is 2 entities (both on same table `CAR`), each returning different data columns from that table.  So, I am not sure if I need to have 2 entities or just one but get 2 different sets of columns with their data...

Comment: ... but since this is JPA, then how are these going to be created by hibernate.  It seem they will be competing.  Like first will be created CarEntity with 5 columns but then 2nd entity will be created with 2 columns from table `CAR`.  If projections are answer, could you provide me with both entities and both repositories getting the different data from as per above SLQ statements?  Thank you

Comment: I am going to update the answer, you can use the same CarRepository by adding any method. @pixel done.

Comment: That is starting to make sense now, I am going to read about Projections.  Now it looks like it is what I am looking form.  Would you mind clarifying what do you mean with your comment "if you want you can implement JIC"?  and thank you

Comment: Can these repository methods be used with `@Query` annotations?  Because my query might be bit more complicated and also need to sort results?

Comment: @pixel I mean that is not necessary to implement any interface, so it is enough having interfaces containing getter methods which you want to select.

Comment: I think it is working.  If I use your method `Collection<Car> findByAccidentYearIsNull();` I get data that matches colums I am interested in.  However, I am having problem making this method to return `DISTINCT carModel, carYear WHERE carYear IS NOT NULL`.  How would I define this method?...

Comment: ... I tried using `List<CarSummary> findDistinctByCarModelAndCarYearAndCarYearIsNotNull();` but that is failing.  I get error stating that **the method expects at least 1 arguments but only found 0**.

Comment: Because you are not passing cardModel, when you put byCardModel, you should add (String cardmodel, String cardYear) probably last one no, but I see you copied for both not null and null I guess.

Comment: I dont understand.  I am trying to get records mathing `SELECT DISTINCT CAR_MODEL, CAR_YEAR WHERE CAR_YEAR IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CAR_MODEL`.  That is what I am trying to achieve.  So, I dont get it why (and what) to pass into the call to `findDistinctByCarModelAndCarYearAndCarYearIsNotNull()`.  I am trying to read these rows, so how can I know what to pass in?  I am not passing any parameters in the SQL query either so not sure what do you mean I need to pass something into the method.  Can you elaborate and thank you

Comment: Let's separate this method `findDistinctByCarModelAndCarYearAndCarYearIsNotNull()` first `findDistinct` will look for different Cars that is fine, second `ByCardModel` is asking you give an parameter `(String cardmodel)` is missing fi you don't that so use `findDistinctCarByCarYearisNotNull()`. which should work. This is answer resolved your question, please mark it, what you are looking now are other questions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, yes I accept your answer.  Would you be able to help me with the distinct issue, I created it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591332/spring-jpa-repository-method-to-get-sorted-distinct-and-non-null-values?noredirect=1#comment123006720_69591332 and thank you

Comment: The `findDistinctCarByCarYearIsNotNull()` is not failing but it is not returning `DISTINCT CarSummary` but `DISTINCT Car` unfortunatelly.  Any idea?  Much appreciated

Comment: @pixel we can test it, please ping me on my email, I can help you.

Comment: @JonathanJOhx I just sent you email, thank you

Comment: I answered you! @cd491415

Comment: Thanks, I replied.  It is not working and have same problem but I figured out other way but have now problem converting `List<Object>` into `List<CarSummary>` where `CarSummary` is the interface.