# Spring JPA repository method to get sorted distinct and non-null values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

To get distinct data based on **multiple columns** and **exclude NULL** values on a column and **sort the result** in SQL, I would write query like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CAR_NUMBER, CAR_NAME
FROM CAR
WHERE CAR_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CAR_NUMBER
```

This would return me rows with distinct values for CAR_NUMBER and CAR_NAME and it would exclude any rows having CAR_NUMBER = NULL and finally, it would sort the result by CAR_NUMBER.

However, In Spring JPA, I gather you can use either methods named based on your entity fields or using `@Query` annotation.

I am trying to do this:

```java
List<Car> findDistinctByCarNumberAndCarNameAndCarNumberIsNotNull(Sort sort);
```

, and to call this method like:

```java
myRepo.findDistinctByCarNumberAndCarNameAndCarNumberIsNotNull(Sort.by("carNumber"));
```

but this is failing on Maven > Install with error like "**findDistinctByCarNumberAndCarNameAndCarNumberIsNotNull(Sort sort) expects at least 1 arguments but only found 0**".

Similarly, I tried using `@Query` like below but with same effect:

```java
@Query(SELECT DISTINCT c.carNumber, c.carName FROM carEntity c WHERE c.carNumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY c.carNumber)
List<Car> findAllCars();
```

Comment: nativeQuery does not support sorting

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 Could you please remove your comment, I dont want to pollute my question with discussions.  Thank you

Comment: I wrote out one of my earlier suggestions you turned down, I tested it on a project of mine now that I had an IDE and a data table to my disposal, cheers.

Comment: I would suggest changing your title to something more suitable to the problem, so other people can also profit from your question, the issue is rather that Query DSL doesn't have a way to handle your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  Following is how I solved it:

In my repository:

```
@Query("select distinct c.carNumber, c.carName from CarEntity c where c.carNumber is not null")
List<Object> findAllDistinctRegions(Sort sort);
```

Important here to realize is that `@Query` returns `List<Object>`, not `List<Car>`.

Next, in my service, call this method:

```
    List<Object> carData = carRepository.findAllDistinctCars(Sort.by("carNumber"));
```

That worked finally fine; however, I run into another problem where I had to do necessary conversion from List to List.

```
    // This is bit tricky as the returned List<Object> is actually
    // List<Object[]>.  Basically, each field returned by the @Query 
    // is placed into an array element.  
    //To solve it, I had to do following:
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    for(Object data: carsData) {
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) data;
        cars.add(new CarDto((Short) obj[0], ((String) obj[1]));
    }
```

Comment: I thought it was weird that @Query didn't work. It basically does the same as my example, using AOP behind the scenes. I did point out that you weren't getting back the full entity btw. In your question you said that you were getting the same error, so I gave you another alternative. I'm glad you got it to work. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered there is a better way to solve this than that helper function that you described in your answer and thought I would share it.

Projection in JPQL would be a cleaner way to create your DTO:

```java
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT new com.yourdomain.example.models.MyDto(c.carNumber, c.carName)
FROM CarEntity c WHERE c.carNumber is not null")
List<CarDto> findAllDistinctRegions(Sort sort);
```